# Cordova Push notifitication badge not displaying on app icon iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification

I am using [cordova push plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) where I am getting notification and all data I needed, but also I want to set badge as per the unread notification or the number i am getting into count of push notification but I am not sure why I am not getting this count as a badge into app icon of iOS device

Here is the json format I am getting into push notification success function

```
{
    "count":"1",
    "sound":"default",
    "additionalData":{
        "foreground":true,
        "product_id":"19",
        "user_id":"2",
        "coldstart":false,
        "notificationstatus":"like"
    },
    "message":"Username likes your product"
}
```

Sound and message both were working perfect but not count.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you sure that push notification is received by your device?

Comment: Yes I am testing this from my device right now.

Comment: @KirankumarDafda Did you checked this link by any chance - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that, there is a string value of `count` in the response, and it was the mistake.

Count value must be an `integer`.

Hope this will help others too.

Comment: Welcome @KirankumarDafda. Happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

what you receiving is ok but one key is wrong. the key `count` should be `badge`. This is the problem i think. Try to change the key and reply the result.

reference - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html

Comment: We are passing `badge` keyword into the aps but it is automatically convert `badge` to `count` into the response